# Haskell - Passing multiple functions into a function

Tags: haskell, higher-order-functions

Im trying to test passing two functions into 'myfunc' to perform operations of the elements of an Int list.

*This is purely to test -- i know I can use filter, even etc.. just testing code here

```
 addone :: Int -> Int
 addone i = i + 1
 addoone _ = 0

checkeven :: Int -> Bool
checkeven n 
   | even n == True = True
   | otherwise      = False

myfunc :: (Int -> Bool) -> (Int -> Int) -> [Int] -> [Int]
myfunc ce ao [] = []
myfunc _ ao (x : xs) = []
myfunc ce _ (x : xs) = []
myfunc ce ao (x : xs) = if ce x then ao x : tail else tail where
   tail = myfunc ce ao xs

mylist = [1,2,3,3,3,1,1,4]
main = do
  let x = myfunc checkeven addone mylist
  putStrLn $ show x
```

Getting an error when trying to run this of 'Non-exhaustive patterns'... Any ideas?

Comment: Please always add the full error message. And be sure to actually post the code as you've tested it (use `ctrl-k` to make it a code block, so you won't mess up the indentation).

Comment: I think you will not get past the second line of impl. in myfunc since it will match any input that is not the empty list, and the empty list is matched in the first line. it looks like you are trying to validate that the two functions have been passed (similar to are not null) but that is redundant

Comment: Rather than writing out an explicit recursive function, try to compose existing functions. `myfunc ce ao xs = map ao (filter ce xs)`, or even just `myfunc ce ao = map ao . filter ce`.

Comment: Also, `checkeven` is just a verbose wrapper around `even`: `checkeven = even`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In *myfunc* these two lines are useless because when pattern matching they mean the same thing (also they are not the final stage of the recursion you are looking for) :

```
myfunc _ ao (x : xs) = []
myfunc ce _ (x : xs) = []
```

also in the first pattern match *ce* *ao* are useless, because they are not used anywhere so they should be a *_*.

So *myfunc* should look like this:

```
myfunc :: (Int -> Bool) -> (Int -> Int) -> [Int] -> [Int]
myfunc _ _ [] = []
myfunc ce ao (x : xs) = if ce x then ao x : tail else tail where
   tail = myfunc ce ao xs
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the breakdown:

```
addone :: Int -> Int
addone i = i + 1
addone _ = 0
```

The last line is extraneous here, because first line will match everything.

```
checkeven :: Int -> Bool
checkeven n 
   | even n == True = True
   | otherwise      = False
```

This can be written as `checkeven = even`.

```
myfunc :: (Int -> Bool) -> (Int -> Int) -> [Int] -> [Int]
myfunc ce ao [] = []
myfunc _ ao (x : xs) = []
myfunc ce _ (x : xs) = []
myfunc ce ao (x : xs) = if ce x then ao x : tail else tail where
   tail = myfunc ce ao xs
```

The condition to match line 1 is "the list is empty". Conditions to match line 2 and 3 are "the list isn't empty". Thus, lines 3 and 4 will never be matched.

RE the error, I can't see where it can come from. Please post the full code that reproduces the problem and clear error message.

Comment: Each comment referers to the code above it, not beneath.

Comment: It seems our brains are wired up differently, didn't notice next comment :)